# UART SERCOM on Pins 11-13 Arduino M0 (SAMD21)

Tags: serial, spi, communication, uart, samd21g

I am a newb at coding. Does anyone have any code laying around or some time to write some to send data over UART SERCOM on pins 11/12/13 on a SAMD21 board like the Arduino M0? I am trying to send a double from my LightAPRS W-2 board but can't use I2C and this is my only option.

Comment: why is your time more valuable than anyone else's time? ... what is preventing you from doing reasearch and trying to write your own code? ... there are many examples and tutorials available about Arduino serial communication ... please make an attempt to write the code and post the result of your effort ... describe any problems you are seeing and copy/paste errors here

Comment: See https://learn.adafruit.com/using-atsamd21-sercom-to-add-more-spi-i2c-serial-ports/creating-a-new-serial